Encountering issues locally when trying firebase hosting with Quartz SSG
I have created a site using Quartz SSG. It works locally when i do npx quartz build -d docs --serve, but when i try with Firebase Hosting preview commands like below, site doesn't respond much. Either its 404 or returns back to home page.
firebase serve --only hosting

Below are the things which can be used to reproduce ( https://quartz.jzhao.xyz/ )
git clone https://github.com/jackyzha0/quartz.git

npm install

npx quartz build -d docs --serve

npx quartz build -d docs    

firebase init

firebase serve --only hosting


Firebase.json (default)
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}

Firebase init inputs
=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add,
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

? Please select an option: Use an existing project
? Select a default Firebase project for this directory: zzzyz-361015 (zzzyz)
i  Using project zzzyz-361015 (zzzyz)

=== Hosting Setup

Your public directory is the folder (relative to your project directory) that
will contain Hosting assets to be uploaded with firebase deploy. If you
have a build process for your assets, use your build's output directory.

? What do you want to use as your public directory? public
? Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? No
? Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
? File public/404.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of public/404.html
? File public/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
i  Skipping write of public/index.html

i  Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
i  Writing project information to .firebaserc...

+  Firebase initialization complete!

System Info:
Windows 11 Pro
Node: v22.11.0
Firebase: 13.24.2

Initially had a firebase issue as iam using Node 22, i resolved by following last message in the link
Would like to know if Quartz is not supported by Firebase

Resolved it myself, as there was no response.
Firebase Hosting doesn't support Quartz directly as it supported Gatsby
So, i had to host the site via Cloud Run using Caddy and then had to do firebase deploy --only hosting
Quite a learning. Thanks
